# Cities autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm using this plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/City-Autocomplete-Plugin-with-jQuery-Google-Places-API.html to achieve cities autocomplete in my application. I made a separate folder with needed scripts and html file just for test and everything works fine. However, when I place this code in my project it doesn't work. I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem but with no effect. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Test folder:

[image]

Index file:

[image]

Effect:

[image]

Head section of my application:

[image]

Body section of my application:

[image]

Edit:

_Layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - something</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/city-autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.city-autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>



<div class="container body-content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 logo-left">
            <div class="tymczasowe-logo">Portal aukcyjny</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 logo-right">
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-logo-right">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                    @Html.ActionLink("O nas", "WyswietlOnas", "Zakladki", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Regulamin", "WyswietlRegulamin", "Zakladki", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Kontakt", "WyswietlKontakt", "Zakladki", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("something", "something", "something")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("something", "something", "something")</li>

                </ul>

                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()

</div>

<footer>
    <hr />
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - something</p>
</footer>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Content of file rendered in @RenderBody:

```
@using PortalAukcyjny.Models
@model Rejestracja


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "something";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <legend>something</legend>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:solid 1px green">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.something.something)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.something.something)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.somethingy.something)
    </div>



    <input id="city" name="city" autocomplete="off" data-country="us" />

    <script>
        $('input#city').cityAutocomplete();
    </script>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.something)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.something, Model.something)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.something)
    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}




@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Edit 2:

Now, when everything works I have a problem with polish letters. This change:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

didn't help.

[image]

It should be for example "Międzyzdroje".

Comment: Please tell us if you have errors in console

Comment: There are no errors. Autocomplete just doesn't work.

Comment: Please delete `@Script.Render` and `@Style.Render` from top of the page.

Comment: Still I don't see a list of cities :(

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Solution is to include your `layout` in your view, bacause you need to use scripts from layout.

```
@using PortalAukcyjny.Models
@model Rejestracja

@{
   Layout="your_layout_path";
   ViewBag.Title = "something";
}
```

2) You need to include an api key.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @Artur, please try now.

Comment: I added this code: @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "something";
} but still with no effect.

Comment: And if you include your scripts in view ?

Comment: It doesn't help either. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have, how can I give you my password?

Comment: Send id and pass to ionutmihai1995@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you again for a teamviewer session !

Comment: One more question. I can't see Polish letters in autocomplete. I set "pl" in Google API reference, data-country="pl" in <input> and also <html lang="pl-PL"> and   <meta charset="utf-8" />.

Comment: Please add language in your script source. Something like this: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=ro&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I did it already:                                       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=somekey&libraries=places&language=pl"></script>

Comment: Try this: language="pl-PL".